# does loading a conditional stylesheet cause an extra server request

Tags: css, internet-explorer, httprequest

I have in my code the likes of:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6_Stylesheet.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7_Stylesheet.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8_Stylesheet.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9_Stylesheet.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I can see that these lines show up in the source code on all my different browsers, but what I want to know is if they actually slow the pages from loading for any browser that isn't IE?

I'm almost sure it doesn't but I can't find definitively and I've been told by someone else that it does cause server requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the conditional stylesheets will *not* be loaded in any other browser except the version of IE that the condition matches. Conditional stylesheets will not generate any extra page requests for non-IE browsers.

Answer (score 1):

These tags are only understood by IE

Other browser consider them to be html comments:

```
<!-- Note this is an html comment -->
```